# Use the date filter on a variable pulled from function within view

Tags: angularjs

I'd like to use the date filter on a variable pulled from a function in my view. However, I keep getting the following error message:

```
Error: [$parse:syntax] Syntax Error: Token '|' is unexpected, expecting [)] at column 201 of the expression [nextStep(3); 
                    sendMessage('xxx', 'xxx', 
                    'Thanks. Your appointment with ' + selectedBusiness.name + ' has been booked for ' + convertDate(booking.date) | date:'fullDate' + ' at ' + booking.time ) + '.'] starting at [| date:'fullDate' + ' at ' + booking.time ) + '.'].
```

What is the alternative? This is my code so far.

```
<a ng-click="sendMessage('xxx', 'xxx', 
'Thanks. Your appointment with ' + selectedBusiness.name + 
  ' has been booked for ' + convertDate(booking.date) | date:'fullDate' + 
  ' at ' + booking.time ) + '.'">Pay</a>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That looks like a fair amount of logic in the template. Couldn't you move that off to a controller?

```js
angular.module('myApp', [])

.controller('MainController', ['$scope', 'dateFilter', 'MessageService',
  function($scope, dateFilter, MessageService) {
    // Don't know where these come from so just mocking out
    $scope.selectedBusiness = {
      name: 'ACME'
    };
    $scope.booking = {
      date: '12/31/2016',
      time: '12:00:00PM'
    };

    // handle logic of assembling message here in the controller.
    // can also be unit tested
    $scope.handlePay = function handlePay(selectedBusiness, booking) {
      var convertedDate = dateFilter(new Date(booking.date), 'fullDate');
      var msgText = 'Thanks. Your appointment with ' + selectedBusiness.name +
        ' has been booked for ' + convertedDate +
        ' at ' + booking.time + '.';

      // hand off to MessageService sendMessage (note: this method could just as easily be on the controller, but sending a message
      // seems like it would be shared functionality
      MessageService.sendMessage('xxx', 'xxx', msgText);
    }
  }
])

.service('MessageService', [
  function MessageService() {
    this.sendMessage = function sendMessage(param1, param2, msgText) {
      // use logic to send message
      alert(msgText);
    }
  }
]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MainController">
  <a href="#" ng-click="handlePay(selectedBusiness, booking)">Pay</a>
</div>
```

**EDIT:** Regarding why your original post wouldn't work. I noticed parenthesis mismatch and needing extra set of parenthesis around the date filter. I would still recommend the controller route, but here is your modified template if you want to keep it there (notice moving the closing parenthesis to the end and enclosing the date filter):

```
<a ng-click="sendMessage('xxx', 'xxx', 
'Thanks. Your appointment with ' + selectedBusiness.name + 
  ' has been booked for ' + (convertDate(booking.date) | date:'fullDate') + 
  ' at ' + booking.time + '.')">Pay</a>
```

Comment: If you want to keep in template, here is a jsfiddle for it working. Looks like you had some parenthesis in the wrong place and needed an extra set of parenthesis around the date filter: https://jsfiddle.net/s6f83xk1/1/